# button href after form is submitted

Tags: php, html

How do I href the user after the form is submit?
(Why? The form is at the bottom of the page, so when the user submits the form they get directed to the top of the page. So I need it to href="#kontakt" after the form is submit)

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitform">
```

This might be obvious to someone, but I am fairly new to html/php

Comment: Where's exactly the `href`?

Comment: I've tried placing it a lot of places, but since none of them worked I didnt include it.

Comment: I tried placing it inside button tag. Wrapped an a tag around with href. None of them worked.

Comment: I guess I'm getting a lot of downvotes because people think I didn't try anything before posting....

Comment: @Zidco, I'd guess that you're getting downvoted because the terminology you're using is misleading. You want to link to an "anchor" on the page via the document fragment, not "href the user".

Comment: I might have explained this poorly, the form already has <form method="post" action="mail.php"> Which makes the form get sent to my email, but after that is done I want it to redirect to #kontakt

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`action`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#attr-fs-action) attribute to specify what URL the form should submit to. If you need a document fragment, you can add that there as well.

[Working example on codepen](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/jrbrLG)

Here's a stack snippet as well, however it won't work due to the sandboxed nature of the `<iframe>`:

```css
:target {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form action="#example" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="example">
  <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
<div id="example">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the action attribute :

```
<form action="kontakt.php">
...
</form>
```